# Building website for domino server

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I need to make a small website to be hosted at a domino server but as far as I understand, I couldn't use a simple .html file or .php, instead it works with some weird stuff like .nsf, right? Also, it isn't clear to me wich language is used to deploy webpages with domino server, and if there is a good book about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with Lotus Domino 8.5.x you can create web applications using XPages. XPages "*is based on web development languages and standards including JavaScript, Ajax, Java, the Dojo Toolkit, Server-side JavaScript and JavaServer Faces*" (source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPages).

If you are interested in learning more about XPages, the following book is very useful:
[Mastering XPages: A Step-by-Step Guide to XPages Application Development and the XSP Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132486318)

There is also the "classic" way of creating web applications with Lotus Domino if using XPages is not an option. The following book provides a good overview of that method:
[IBM Lotus Domino: Classic Web Application Development Techniques](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849682402)

Answer (score 6):

You can use simple static html files but the beauty of Domino is that you can develop dynamically created web sites using the back end database processes.

If you want to do something with just html then drop your html files into the /domino/html folder and they will be served out.

If you want to do something more powerful start at http://www.xpages.info which is run by the Open Source community for Domino.

There are quite a few out of the box projects available such as Wikis, "Team Rooms", discussion forums, blogs and   document libraries. Some of these are also packaged with the domino install. Some of these are content management systems with some of the same functionality as wordpress or Joomla and might work well for you.

Some examples : http://xpages.info/XPagesHome.nsf/Demos.xsp

As with any platform there are quirks and gotchas but it is a brilliant platform. Contact me if you need a better steer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the domino/html approach or you could utilize the new web development interface and environment in Domino, since 8.5, called XPages. It's a technology derived from JSP (Java Server Pages) using standard web methods and technologies such as Java, JavaScript, AJAX, DOJO, CSS working with predefined Custom Controls giving you the drag and drop approach to development.

Several book are on the market, one of them close to release:

[XPages Portable Command Guide: A Compact Resource to XPages Application Development and the XSP Language](http://www.ibmpressbooks.com/bookstore/product.asp?isbn=9780132943055)

[Mastering XPages: A Step-by-Step Guide to XPages Application Development and the XSP Language](http://www.ibmpressbooks.com/bookstore/product.asp?isbn=9780132694902)

[XPages Extension Library: A Step-by-Step Guide to the Next Generation of XPages Components](http://www.ibmpressbooks.com/bookstore/product.asp?isbn=9780132901864)

Answer (score 2):

For instructional videos, there's [XPages.tv (Videos)](http://xpages.tv/)

Answer (score 1):

While a Domino server typically is used to host Notes application (**.nsf** files), you can use it to host raw HTML files. The default root for this is the `domino\html` directory.

The documentation on [web server configuration](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc%2FDOC%2FH_OVERVIEW.html) has more details on this.

[Configuring HTML, CGI, icon, and Java files for Web Site documents](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_CONFIGURE_INTERNET_SITES_DOCUMENT_STEPS.html)

Answer (score 1):

The following tech note details how to run PHP on a Domino server, although Domino itself does not have PHP.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21099845

There is also this article on how to create PHP for Domino.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-php/

Answer (score 1):

### Host a static html file in a different place to domino directory

If you want to persist your static html files in a different place to `domino\html` then you can do this in the following way:

1. Configure a new WebSite for your domino server:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_10.0.1/admin/conf_configuringhtmlcgiiconandjavafilesforwebsite_t.html

2. Copy your files to the specified folder on your server's disk.

**Example:**

---

Website:

[image]

File on domino server:

[image]

Open in browser:

[image]

*With this approach I have deployed a complete angular single page application on a domino server.*